# Running command in existing shell from gvim

Tags: linux, shell, vim, ipc

It all starts from a shell. For example I am using `urxvt` with `zsh`. There I open some file with `gvim`. In this case it is a `LaTeX` file. Now I need to execute some command (for compiling the document, e.g.`pdflatex`).

How can I have the original shell, from where `gvim` was started, execute that command?

It would also be acceptable if `gvim` had to open a new shell *once* and after that execute every future call of the designated command (`pdflatex`) in that shell, while I can still type in it manually.

The problem with running `:!pdflatex` directly is, that the output is shown, but if it has gotten too long scrolling is not possible and after I press return, it is all gone.

The idea with using a shell means, that the window focus does not have to switch over by default. So in general the output of my command is visible, but unless an error occurs I can just keep on working in `gvim`. Now if a new shell was spawned everytime I run the command, this kind of workflow would certainly not be possible.

Comment: I guess gedit has this feature of console. Please have a look. Will get back with more details.

Comment: Can you explain further the need of using a single shell?

Comment: @mtk: sorry, but I won't switch to another editor.

Comment: @mMontu: I added an explanation; hope that clears things up.

Comment: @canaa was a thought, I too stick to VIM, none other is as comforatble as it is :)

Comment: @canaaerus: if I understood correctly, the final need is to be able to see the results of previous commands you execute to compile the document. Vim has several features that would help in this task, as `quickfix` - there are some references on [vim-faq](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-28.1). This would allow you to see the results of compilation inside of Vim. Previous results are still available through `:cp` command, and it would also allow you to jump to specific lines referenced from the errors, despite being able to navigate through results using Vim amazing features.

Comment: @mMontu: Thank you for the hints. In fact I now revisited `vim-latex`'s compile features, which are based on this. I'll have to see how good they really work.

Comment: @canaaerus: nice! I hope it solves your problem, is far more cleaner than trying to somehow hooking a shell instance. Let me know if you have troubles using the `quickfix window` - it works very well for the languages I use, despite it took sometime until I found about some commands, as `:cp` and `:cw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GVIM does not retain a "handle" to the shell that launched it in a way that allows it to send commands back to it. Because of they synchronous execution, you also cannot launch a shell from GVIM, keep feeding it commands while also continue working in GVIM.

I'm afraid you have to use the functionality of your window manager to launch (and then later re-activate) a shell window, and send the commands as keystrokes to it. On Windows, this can be done (e.g. in VBScript) via `WshShell`'s `Run()`, `AppActivate()` and `SendKeys()` methods; there are probably similar mechanisms for window control on Linux, too.

If you don't mind having that shell *inside* your GVIM (emulated, with all its drawbacks), though, there are plugins that enable that.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to pass along a handle when starting `gvim`, perhaps with `gvim -c`. Well, I'll just try `conque` and see if the drawbacks are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Conque](http://code.google.com/p/conque/). It has drawbacks (can be slow, not so frequently updated, etc) but at least it works for what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

The Vim Wiki as [this recipe,](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Compiling_LaTeX_from_Vim#Manual_setup) which I think will solve your problem by completely removing the need for an external shell. Here it is, in case the source goes dark:

```
let b:tex_flavor = 'pdflatex'
compiler tex
set makeprg=pdflatex\ \-file\-line\-error\ \-interaction=nonstopmode
set errorformat=%f:%l:\ %m
```

Basically, you use `:make` to compile and the quickfix window (`:copen`) to list errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell commands in vim by calling `!command`.

For your particular use case of running pdflatex, I added the following shortcut in my `/etc/vimrc`:

```
:nmap <F5> :w<CR>:make<CR>
```

`:make` will call [gnu make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) in the current directory which will eventually call `pdflatex`. This is very flexible since the same shortcut will do different thing depending on the directory where you are (if you are coding in C, it will typically call `gcc`). But you have to be fluent with make :).

So hitting F5 saves my document and compiles it, and saved me hours of typing for multiple years now :).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately you missed the main point of the question. The command should not be run in a temporary shell and its output printed inside the `gvim` window, but in an dedicated console window.

Comment: then start this dedicated console window with !urxvt "whatever"